# Using different versions of the same library in a single process

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, cmake

I have a problem in C++/CMake.

Lets say I have `thing1.exe` that uses `MyLib_v1.dll`.

And lets say I have `thing2.exe` that uses `MyLib_v2.dll`.

`thing1.exe` and `thing2.exe` are meant to be run in parallel and pass data between them (using queues or whatever).

I need to transition from 2 separate `.exe` files to a single one with multiple threads (assume no conflict in global variables, etc.).

However I cannot include 2 different versions of `MyLib` since they define the same function and namespaces.

And I cannot change what versions of `MyLib` are used.

I have an idea of compiling `thing1` and `thing2` to `.dll` files, making them each include/load their preferred versions of `MyLib`, and then having a central `.exe` that calls the functionality of `thing1.dll` and `thing2.dll` like this:

```
root/
├─ thing1libs/
│  ├─ MyLib_v1.dll
├─ thing2libs/
│  ├─ MyLib_v2.dll
├─ thing1.dll
├─ thing2.dll
├─ main.exe
```

Is this possible using something like CMake? Or will the 2 versions of `MyLib` still clash inside `main.exe`?

Comment: Given your constraints, I believe the scenario you describe will run into an endless series of unsolvable problems.  Unless you can have two additional separate processes, one which hosts MyLib_v1.dll and one which hosts MyLib_v2.dll and communicate to them from your thingBoth.exe using interprocess communication.

Comment: If you statically link against the DLL then you will still have the problem that symbols are ambigous. You would have to load the respective DLLs manually and resolve the smybols yourself, but this opens another can of worms.

Comment: Cmake's involvement here is limited to executing the prescribed commands to compile and link your code, as per your instructions. Cmake has nothing to do, whatsoever, with anything else including whether the end result works or not (very unlikely).

Comment: Not with cmake, but it is definitely possible in the source code with some handywork (depending on how many function pointers). I usually wrap the necessary winapi calls in a dedicated class that exposes the dll services.